# Airtight seal around ceiling lamp holder

Tags: sealing, lamp

I would like to make an airtight seal around a cheap IKEA ceiling lamp holder since I started having silverfish creep out of it and fall into the lamp.  (One silverfish every few days for the past two weeks—they are fortunately unable to climb out of the ceiling lamp.)  What would be the best way to do so?  Ideally something beginner-friendly that can be removed afterwards while leaving the wires intact.  You can find attached photos of the ceiling lamp holder and the entire lamp in question.

[image: Ceiling lamp holder]
[image: Ceiling lamp]

Comment: Could you please post a photo of the whole lamp

Comment: @RohitGupta – Added one.

Comment: silver fish in the ceiling ?

Comment: What type of bub, wattage?

Comment: @Ruskes – I assume they‘re coming through the conduit.  The ceiling is otherwise concrete, so I doubt they’re in there.

Comment: @JACK – E27, the socket is rated for 13W, the lamp is 11W.

Comment: This is an apartment building in Germany.  The lamp in question is in the bathroom.  There is ventilation but no windows; I have (and have had) the ventilation running all the time.  The bathroom is certainly not too humid; e.g., I’ve never had the mirror fog up (but I don’t have a hygrometer to tell for sure).  Unfortunately, I’ve no idea what the situation is like at my neighbors’.

Comment: they live in drains, so clean you drain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually caulk can be used to seal gaps in fixtures. Make sure you seal any unused screw mounting holes in the fixture. If you still believe the silver fish are coming through the conduit, apply some caulk to the end of it. You can also get some foam weather stripping from your home store and use it to seal the fixture.

Comment: +1 on the weatherstripping.  Much less permanent than the caulk.

Comment: Thank you very much!  My landlord has agreed to call pest control (even though the situation has been quiet for the past few days), so I’ll see what they have to say first, as I’m afraid to take down the ceiling lamp holder fearing that some of them might fall to the ground.  Afterwards, I’ll take down the holder, put some weather stripping on it, and screw it back on.  I assume that’s what you meant, right?

Comment: @bletted.medlar   Yes, that's what I meant. Y might not even have to take it down, just loosen the screws enough to lower it and then push in the weather stripping.